# zend framework fetch all ORDER BY desc

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im trying to get the company name ORDER BY ASC or DECS but what I have tired doesnt seem to work...Im new to Zend Framework and inherited this application, now having to make updates to it, I have been reading Zend docs on their site...any feedback, examples would be appreciated

This is in my model

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_X2payUsers extends 
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
protected $_name = 'users';
protected $_primary = 'id';

public function getAllUsers(){
    $users = $this->fetchAll(Zend_db::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $users = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY DECS');


    $result = array();
    foreach($users as $user){
        $result [$user->id]= $user->company_name;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This is the transaction filter form Im working with

```
 class Application_Form_TransactionFilter extends Zend_Form
 {

private $_company = '';

public function __construct($company = '') {
    $this->_company = $company;

    return parent::__construct();
}

public function init()
{
    $this->setName('transaction-filter');
    $this->setAction('');
    $this->setMethod('GET');

    $users_table = new Application_Model_DbTable_X2Users();
    $users = $users_table->getAllUsers();
    // ->orderby('company_name ASC');

    $company = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('company');
    $company->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty') 
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->removeDecorator('label')
            ->removeDecorator('htmlTag')
            ->removeDecorator('Errors');    
    $company->addMultiOptions(
        array(''=>'-- Select Company --')
    );
    $company->addMultiOptions($users);
    $company->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please select a company');

    $company->setValue($this->_company);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('class', 'btn btn-default')
            ->setLabel('Submit')
            ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
             ->removeDecorator('label')
             ->removeDecorator('htmlTag');      
    $this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript',
            array('viewScript' => '_transaction_filter.phtml'))));        
    $this->addElements(array($company, $submit));  
}
```

}

This is the code in the transaction file

```
   <?= $this->filter ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **fetchAll** method of **Zend_Db_Table_Abstract**, 1st argument can be:

- null
- Zend_Db_Table_Select
- string or array, that will be used as a condition

**2nd argument is the order** and can be the order sql, eg "company_name DESC" or an array of multiple orders, eg `array("company_name DESC", "id ASC")`. This is want you want to use in your case

One way to do this is:

```
public function getAllUsers(){
    $users = $this->fetchAll(null, 'company_name DESC');

    $result = array();
    foreach($users as $user){
        $userArray = $user->toArray();
        $result [$userArray['id']]= $userArray['company_name'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[Zend 1.12 db documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html)

[Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php#L1371)

Comment: awesome, thank you so much...will continue reading the documentation as well